# Android. Не обновляется виджет приложения

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь реализовать обновление виджета по таймеру.

В результате виджет обновляется только в двух случаях:

1. При запуске устройства;
2. При удалении и повторном добавлении виджета.

Проблема воспроизводится и на устройстве и на эмуляторе. Использую Android 4.2.2.

Код виджета.

**Java**

```
private static String getDate() {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    return dateFormat.format(new Date());
}

public static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,int appWidgetId) {
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.info_widget);
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_textHeader, getDate());
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
}

public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context,appWidgetManager,appWidgetIds);
    updateAppWidget(context,appWidgetManager,appWidgetIds[0]);
}
```

**XML**

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/info_widget"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/info_widget"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:minWidth="110dp"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/example_appwidget_preview"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="5000"
    >
</appwidget-provider>
```

Перепробовал уже многое. В том числе некоторые решения с этого сайта, но пока безрезультатно.

Однако, вполне вероятно, я что-то делаю не так.

Answer (score 1):

В общем разобрался самостоятельно. Данная проблема, как оказалось, легко решается с помощью простого таймера.

Детали.

Создаём член класса - экземпляр `Timer`.

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer();
```

Прописываем в нём обновление виджета. Например, так:

```
private void startTimer(final Context context, final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                            final int appWidgetId) {
        myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
            }
        }, 0, 2000);
}
```

После этого запускаем таймер из onUpdate.

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
    int[] appWidgetIds) {
            super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);                
            startTimer(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds[0]);
}
```

Информация в виджете будет обновляться каждый раз спустя определённый интервал времени (в данном примере 2 секунды).

P.S. Разумеется, не забываем останавливать таймер, когда он уже не нужен.

```
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    myTimer.cancel();
}
```